# extending very short voltage peak with capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I want to measure the hight of a very short voltage peak using an analog input It does not have to be very exact. the duration of that peak is between 1 and 2 milliseconds, is it possible to extend the duration a bit using a capacitor? obviously it won't be parabolic anymore but that is not a big problem, the only requirement is that it is gone after about 50ms is this doable?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site. What did you mean about "analog input".

Comment: The analog input of an arduino

Answer (score 0):

you can use a diode to stop the voltage from immedately draining out of the capacitor. but the diode will reduce the voltage a little.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEIzi6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thanks, reducing the voltage is not a big problem, only the relative voltages compared to other peaks are important! gonna try this!

Comment: @remcoh, how much effect this has on your measured voltage should be checked...if the source has a high impedance compared to the capacitor, it could read much lower than expected.